# problems bootstrap-table with confirmation modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am having difficulty implementing a confirmation modal for the delete event of a table created with bootstrap-table (bootstrap v3.3).

Here is the toolbar for the table (note modal specification for delete button)

```
<!--Button-->
<div id="toolbar" class="btn-group btn-default">
 <button class="btn btn-default" id="create">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i> <span>New</span>
 </button>
 <button class="btn btn-default" id="show">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></i> <span>Show</span>
 </button>
 <button class="btn btn-default" id="edit">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> <span>Edit</span>
 </button>
 <button class="btn btn-default" id="delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmModal">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> <span>Delete</span>
 </button>
</div>
```

here is the table

```
<!--Table-->
<div id="list">
  <table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true" data-search="true
" data-show-refresh="true" data-show-columns="true" data-toolbar="#toolbar">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
        <th data-field="phn" data-sortable="true">Personal Health #</th>
        <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Full Name</th>
        <th data-field="preferred_name" data-sortable="true">Preferred Name</th>
        <th data-field="sex" data-sortable="true">Sex</th>
        <th data-field="date_of_birth" data-sortable="true">Date of Birth</th> 
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

These two pieces were written by a colleague, so I don't understand explicitly how it works. There is a table.js file linked to the view which implements the functionalities of the toolbar.

Within table.js file the section related to delete is as follows

```
$(function () {
  console.log( "Table loaded" );

  $('#table').bootstrapTable()
  .on('all.bs.table', function (e, name, args) {
    console.log('Event:', name, ', data:', args);
  }) 
   ...
   $('#delete').click(function () {
    var path = $(location).attr('pathname');
    var path = path + '/ajax';
    var token = {
      _token: $('#token').attr('value')
    };
```

I have added to the view the following

```
</div>
<!--Confirmation Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog aria-labell
edby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h1>Are you sure?</h1>
        </div>
     <div class="modal-body">

     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cance
l</button>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger danger">Delete</a>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously this needs some javascript to tell the modal what action to take. However the examples I have found don't quite fit with this approach and I don't know javascript well enough to even guess where to start.

At the moment pressing delete on the toolbar deletes the selection and invokes the modal at the same time. So I believe only a simple {{ pending action }} style script to pause the "delete" action, pending the outcome of the modal, is needed.

Can anyone clarify how to do this?

Thanks
-james